# VBA clear contents from cells in row if range of rows in column match range from column in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I think I am very close but I cant figure out how to solve this issue. Everything looks right. I have data sht1 column "T2" with "MO123" Which matches 1 of row in column B on Sht2, not sure if its complaining about the .ClearContent or my range. Thank you for any help you can give me. I will add the code just in case you want to try it out. -Paul

```
Sub Delete_Picklist_Rec()
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet, Sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, lookup_rng As Range, x


    Set Sht1 = Sheets("Pick Ticket Schedule")
    Set Sht2 = Sheets("Pick Ticket (History)")
    Set lookup_rng = Sht2.Range("B2:B7")

    With Sht1
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox "LstRw:" & LstRw
        For x = LstRw To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(x, 1) = lookup_rng Then
                Range("J" & x & ":K" & x).ClearContents Shift:=xlUp 'Need to delete value in cell J & K for the row that matches
            End If
        Next x

    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the `Shift:=xlUp` for a _ClearContents_ as it only clears the cells contents (as it says). It doesn't delete the cell. The error is telling you that the argument you've given (the Shift) doesn't exist for _ClearContents_. If you do want to delete and shift up instead of just clearing then replace `.ClearContents` with `.Delete` and keep the _Shift_

Comment: Also at the start of the clear line you just use `Range`. You should specify the sheet by making it `.Range` if it's supposed to happen on your _Sht1_ or `Sht2.Range` if it's supposed to happen on _Sht2_. At the moment your clearing happens on the **ActiveSheet** as no sheet is specified for it.

Comment: @Simon Ok, Thank you. Now I am getting a type mismatch error. IS this because lookup_rng ,since its a range isnt the same type as the cell value I am comparing it to? On the spreadsheet itself, its the same datatype "MO123", the only difference I can see is one column is in a table being pulled from database. The column on Sht1 is a copy of it. Is it mainly because I'm trying to compare and range to a cell? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you need is to do a find to see if it exists within the range. You are correct you can't compare a single value to a whole range. Try something like this for your If statement: `If Not lookup_rng.Find(what:=.Cells(x,1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @Simon, Thanks you!!!!! That worked like a charm. Saved me hours of grief. Have a great evening!

Comment: You are right to loop from bottom to top. What should happen on each match? `1.)` If you use  `ClearContents`, the data in `A` will be preserved and the data in `J:K` will stay aligned. `2.)` If you delete the cells with `xlShifUp`, the data in `A` will be preserved but the data in `J:K` will be deleted and the remaining data will not be aligned. `3.)` Most often you want to delete the entire rows. You will lose the data in all columns keeping the remaining data aligned. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of there being an answer so everyone knows it's solved:

The first issue was `Shift:=xlUp` isn't a argument for `ClearContents` (it has no arguments) so removing that allows the clear to work. Alternatively you can use `.Delete` instead and utilize the `Shift` argument then.

Secondly you didn't specify the sheet for your *Range* so it by default used the *Active Sheet*.

Thirdly, you're comparing a single cell value to a range which needs to be done either by a find command or looping. I've used the `Find` command as it's typically the fastest solution for something like this. It also has more arguments than what I've used so if needed you can add them to it. Check out more about the find command [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Here is the solution based on what I have said:

```
Sub Delete_Picklist_Rec()
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet, Sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, lookup_rng As Range, x As Long


    Set Sht1 = Sheets("Pick Ticket Schedule")
    Set Sht2 = Sheets("Pick Ticket (History)")
    Set lookup_rng = Sht2.Range("B2:B7")

    With Sht1
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox "LstRw:" & LstRw
        For x = LstRw To 1 Step -1 'Doesn't need to loop backwards if just clearing but does if using Delete.
            If Not lookup_rng.Find(what:=.Cells(x,1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                .Range("J" & x & ":K" & x).ClearContents 'Or .Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next x

    End With

End Sub
```