# ClearContents affects formulas in other cells which are next to it

Tags: excel, vba

When I use `ClearContent` on a cells which other cells next to it uses formulas, it changes the formulas in those other cells. For example:

```
.Range("L" & x2 & ":M" & x2).ClearContents
```

I have formula in N2 which is now `=IFERROR(F3/G3*3600,0)`, I need it to stay `=IFERROR(F2/G2*3600,0)`, the next row N3 now is `=IFERROR(#REF!/#REF!*3600,0)`

Actual Code:

```
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet, Sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, lookup_rng As Range, x
    Dim Sht3 As Worksheet, Sht4 As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw2 As Long, lookup_rng2 As Range, x2

    Set Sht1 = Sheets("Pick Ticket Schedule")
    Set Sht2 = Sheets("Pick Ticket (History)")
    Set lookup_rng = Sht2.Range("B2:B10")

    With Sht1
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = LstRw To 2 Step -1
        'MsgBox "LstRw:" & LstRw & " " & x & "-" & .Cells(x, 20).Value & " -->" & lookup_rng.Value
            If Not lookup_rng.Find(what:=.Cells(x, 20), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                Sht1.Range("J" & x & ":K" & x).ClearContents 'Shift:=xlUp <-- Only used for delete 'Need to delete value in cell J & K for the row that matches
                Sht1.Range("T" & x).ClearContents
            End If
        Next x
    End With
    
    Set Sht3 = Sheets("Master Production Schedule")
    Set Sht4 = Sheets("Historical FG")
    Set lookup_rng2 = Sht4.Range("B2:B10")

    With Sheets("Master Production Schedule")
        LstRw2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row
        For x2 = LstRw2 To 2 Step -1
            If lookup_rng2.Find(what:=.Cells(x2, 22), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                .Range("L" & x2 & ":M" & x2).ClearContents  'Need to delete value in cell L & M for the row that matches
                .Range("T" & x2).ClearContents
                .Range("V" & x2).ClearContents
            End If
        Next x2
    End With
```

Column O with cells O2 and O3 are also affected in a similar way, I am assuming these 2 are somehow affected by Column L & M. Only Row 2 and Row 3 have data for those columns. What would be the best way to make it so it doesn't affect the following rows? Thanks in advance! -Paul

Comment: No, `ClearContents` does not cause `#REF!`s. Deleting cells does.

Comment: @GSerg Well I would think that but here is the code from a different thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69547872/vba-clear-contents-from-cells-in-row-if-range-of-rows-in-column-match-range-from?noredirect=1#comment122932927_69547872)

Comment: @PaulYang - that link seems to be something different from what you're reporting.  There's something else going on which we're not seeing in your post.  Does your workbook have any event handlers?

Comment: @PaulYang, in the different thread you linked to, there a couple of mentions of using `.Delete`. This could be causing your issue with `#REF`. But without your entire code, its difficult to comment.

Comment: @Gangula I will add the code to my original post so that you can see it. Thanks!

Comment: Awwww, interesting..... The problem only occurs on Sht3 and Sht4. Sht1 and Sht2 does not have the same issue and works just fine.

Comment: And that is why @TimWilliams asked about event handlers on those sheets.

Comment: All those cells reference the fields in the refreshable table. So for instance if the refreshable table has 2 rows with the last row in row 3, then the formula in row 2 (since row 1 is headers) references E3 & F3 instead of what I want which is using E2 and F2 in the formula.  Code below doesnt fix it `code`Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(F2/G2*3600*3600,"""")"
    Range("O2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((E2/60)+C2*(N2/60)*(RC[-1]/60),"""")"
    Range("N2:O2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("N3:O200").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pastet`code`

Comment: I tried using the code in my previous post to change the actual formula in the cells but it gives me an error 400 at ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(F2/G2*3600*3600,"""")". I used the macro recorder to record it then replace the code in there with my preferred code F2/G2. What would be the right way to do it?